# GLFW get Monitors count = 0, two other monitors are attached

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, multiple-monitors

Here is my simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {

    int count;
    GLFWmonitor** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&count); 
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason it keeps telling me that there is zeros monitors. I assume 0 means that there really is 1. But I have two other monitors attached to my computer. When I go into system preferences I can clearly see the other two monitors. But i don't know why it keeps telling me zero. I have no clue what the issue would be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to call `glfwInit()` before you do anything else.

From the glfw documentation:

> int glfwInit (void)
>
> This function initializes the GLFW library. Before most GLFW functions
>   can be used, GLFW must be initialized, and before a program terminates
>   GLFW should be terminated in order to free any resources allocated
>   during or after initialization.
>
> If this function fails, it calls glfwTerminate before returning. If it
>   succeeds, you should call glfwTerminate before the program exits.
>
> Additional calls to this function after successful initialization but
>   before termination will succeed but will do nothing.
>
> Returns
>       GL_TRUE if successful, or GL_FALSE if an error occurred.